Weird sliding glitch in ScrollView SwiftUI
this is my first post and english is not my primary language so I'm asking for your understanding.
I'm facing strange behavior in scrollview but in most of the time I cannot reproduce it. The problem is when I scroll down the view at the bottom is sliding constantly (looped). I don't have any clue why is this happening occasionally.
Some fragments of code for my SuggestionsBannerView, and ScrollView which contains it below. This works most of the time so I don't know what causes this effect.
Maybe somebody could help me with this issue.
How it looks
SuggestionsBannerView:
var body: some View {
     content
         .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: bannerType.height)
         .background(background)
         .padding(.horizontal, 16)
         .padding(.vertical, bannerType == .small ? .zero : 16)
         .padding(.bottom, bannerType == .small ? 6 : .zero)
}

@ViewBuilder
    private var content: some View {
        switch bannerType {
        case .standard:
            standardBanner
        case .small:
            smallBanner
        case .largeFreebies:
            largeBanner
        }
    }

    private var standardBanner: some View {
        HStack {
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 2) {
                Group {
                    title
                    subtitle
                }
                .foregroundColor(.purpleMedium)
                .lineLimit(1)
            }
            .padding(.leading, 16)
            .layoutPriority(1)

            Spacer(minLength: .zero)
            image
        }
    }

ScrollView:
private func contentScrollView(width: CGFloat) -> some View {
        ScrollViewReader { value in
            OffsetObservingScrollView(axes: .vertical, offset: $offset) {
                VStack {
                    suggestionsSmallBannerView
                    storiesView.id(Constants.dashboardTopViewID)
                    sliderView
                    bestsellersSectionView
                    specialCategoriesSectionView
                    customGridSectionView(width: width)
                    suggestionsBannerView.id(Constants.dashboardBottomViewID)
                }
                .frame(alignment: .leading)
                .padding(.bottom, Constants.Globals.bottomBarHeight)
            }
            .onChange(of: viewModel.scrollToBottom) { shouldScroll in
                guard shouldScroll else { return }

                withAnimation {
                    value.scrollTo(Constants.dashboardBottomViewID, anchor: .top)
                }
            }
            .onChange(of: viewModel.scrollToTop) { _ in
                withAnimation {
                    value.scrollTo(Constants.dashboardTopViewID, anchor: .bottom)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private var suggestionsBannerView: some View {
        SuggestionsBannerView()
            .onTapGesture {
                dashboardRouter.route(to: \.suggestions)
            }
            .padding(.top, 16)
            .padding(.bottom, 24)
    }


All your Views need to be in body for SwiftUI to work correctly. Instead of onChange use computed bindings.
